# Facebook post limits

Tags: php, facebook, graph, stream, limit

I created a FB game which allows users to invite there friends. Via the Graph API I retrieve the list of friends and the user selects which friends they want to send a invite. Next the system posts this invite on the friends profile page. This works fine.

But when the users wants to send more than, say 10, invites the API returns this error:
(#341) Feed action request limit reached

I assume this means there is some sort of limit on the amount of posts the system can make on behalf of the user. The users is notified that there will be send an invite to his friend.

Is it possible to get your app certified or something so that the limit will be upgraded. If this isn't possible is there an other way to invite a greater sum of friends.

Regards,
Paul du Long
The Netherlands

Comment: No there's no way to increase that limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

News Feed was not intended for invites.  Use requests instead:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/